# Double vision with Google Cardboard in Unity

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

I am working on a VR app.

I have a terrain and some cube placed in the terrain.Even I have added the Reticle to point at the cube and display some message when the user gaze at the cube.

I have set the distortion to "None".

The problem I am facing here is,when I run the app the cubes and the pointer(reticle) is seeing as double in the scene.What will be the reason for it.Can anybody help me out please.

Comment: Are you seeing double on the screen or are you seeing double *while looking through Google Cardboard*?

Comment: seeing double while looking through google cardboard